# How to Include PHP code in between HTML tags?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

currently I'm developing a application using Codeigniter framework and PHP. In there I need to include below mentioned PHP code in between HTML tags.
Can anyone provide a solution or an guidance for this?

```
PHP code :
             if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) 
                {  
                    echo '<a href="http://localhost/ci/myads_view">';
                    echo 'MY ADS' ;
                    echo '</a>';
                }
HTML code:
         <nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu" role="navigation">
             <ul class="sf-menu"/>
            </nav>
```

Comment: This works. No issue. Make sure if is working.

Comment: It's not css code, it's HTML.

Comment: ah yeah sorry it's html

Comment: Do you want to print the code inside the <ul>? This makes no sense.

Comment: probably outputting before header and/or didn't start the session. This will tell you http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php or CI's method https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: *"ah yeah sorry it's html"* - as in what, `.html` extension? and running from where, hosted site? local machine? if local, how? `http://localhost/file.xxx` or `c:///file.xxx`?

Comment: edit your question to let other viewers know that it is an HTML question and not CSS.

Comment: How to put those css code in between above php code can anyone give me a solution please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can come in and out of PHP at will:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { ?>
  <a href="http://localhost/ci/myads_view">MY ADS</a>
<?php } ?>
```

In the above, if the PHP if statement evaluates to true, the HTML within the conditional will execute, otherwise it will not.

In your particular case, I can only assume this is what you're trying to do:

```
<nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu" role="navigation">
  <ul class="sf-menu">
    <li>
      <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { ?>
        <a href="http://localhost/ci/myads_view">MY ADS</a>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="http://localhost/ci/other-link">OTHER LINK</a>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Or something along the lines of the above?

Answer (score 2):

PHP is pretty cool, you can stop/resume it mid-document.
For example like this, I hope this is the solution to what you were trying to do:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
  { /* this will temporarily "stop" php --> */ ?>
      <a href="http://localhost/ci/myads_view">
          <nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu" role="navigation">
          <ul class="sf-menu">
      </a>
    <?php /* <-- php resumes now */
  }
?>
```

So what's going on?

First, you write your IF statement and the curly brackets, the code inside of which would usually be executed if the IF statement evaluates to TRUE.

```
<?php
  if(something==true)
  {
    echo "write something to the page";
  }
?>
```

But instead of using PHP commands, you quickly jump out of PHP by closing the PHP tag ?> as you would do at the end of your PHP code anyway.

```
<?php
  if(something==true)
  {
    ?>
```

Now you can continue in plain HTML without all the usual related issues of PHP commands as escaping characters like ' and " and \ watching your "qoute level" and so on. Instead, you write bog standard HTML.

When you're done entering the HTML that should be output in case the IF statement is true, just open another PHP tag and close the IF statement's curly brackets and, if that's the end of your PHP, close the PHP tag as well.

```
    <?php
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct, additionally you can write as follows:

```
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
echo $str;
```

Reference - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: what does above lines means i don't understand anything

Comment: This is called heredoc syntax, you don't need to write html tags inside php using echo, instead you can write the entire html block within <<<EOD --- Write whatever you want to write here. EOD tags.

Comment: Search for heredoc syntax online i hope it will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

To put the link inside the navigation, you can do it like this, all inside the same PHP file.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {  
    $navLink= '<a href="http://localhost/ci/myads_view">MY ADS</a>';
}
?>

<nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu" role="navigation">
 <ul class="sf-menu"><?php echo($navLink); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])): ?>  
    <nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu" role="navigation">
    <ul class="sf-menu">
<?php endif; ?>
```